# xlrd extracting range of rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlrd

I'm trying to extract only a particular number of rows from the an excel sheet. I'm able to provide the start, but I don't know how to include the stop value for the row. I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation that can help me with the stop.

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('sheet1')

for row in range(0,worksheet.nrows):
    print(row)
```

I get 1 to 250, which is the end of the spreadsheet. I want to be able to extract only 1 to 125. How do I specify that end?

I tried:

```
    for row in range(0,125,worksheet.nrows):
        print(row)
```

I got 0 0 0 0

How do I get 1,2,3...125?

I using tried the solution [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/6oo46k/xlrd_get_only_value_from_selected_range):

```
worksheet.row_values(0, 0 , 125) for row
```

But I get a syntax error.

All the other answers I found in SO use worksheet.nrows which goes all the way to the end I only want it to go to 125.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**print(sheet.row_values(row_number))**

```
# Program to extract a particular row value 
import xlrd 

loc = ("path of file") 

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 

sheet.cell_value(0, 0) 

print(sheet.row_values(1)) 

Acc To Your code:
for index in range(0,125):
     print(sheet.row_values(index))
```